# Suddenly not able to load HERE maps.Not even on their examples website

Tags: here-api, heremaps

I am not able to load HERE maps, on any of my environments like dev, stage, or prod.
The problem seems to be with the HERE maps **mapsjs-core.js** .

I have further investigated, but it's not even loading on their examples section or on stackblitz.

The specific errors are :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at new Fk (mapsjs-core.js:269)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:71), <anonymous>:16:464)
    at Object.eval (mapsjs-core.js:71)
    at mapsjs-service.js:7
```

**strong text**

Comment: Which version of the mapsjs-core are you using? 3.0 or 3.1?
(for example https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js)

Comment: I tried going to stackblitz and the example section and I didn't come across an example that didn't work. Can you share links to a broken example that you come across?

Comment: Actually, the issue was because of the cache. When I cleared my browser cache then it worked for all.